# Dynamic dropdowns using Firebase's Firestore - AngularFire2

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2, google-cloud-firestore

I have created a collection like so (JSON equivalent):

```
sports: {
  football: {
    name: 'football',
    varieties: {
      11aside: {
        name: '11 a side'
      },
      6aside: {
        name: '6aside'
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I can display the different sports in a select box like so:

```
// sports.controller.ts
this.sports = db.collection('sports').valueChanges();

// sports.html
<select formControlName="sport">
    <option value="">- Select -</option>
    <option *ngFor="let sport of sports | async" [value]="sport.id">{{sport.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Once a selection has been made, I would like to display a 2nd select box, and let the user choose the 'variety'. What would be the best way of achieving this in angularfire2?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't see why this has to be dependent on angularfire2 in particular. Assuming you have initialized your formControl for first select dropdown `sport` as an empty string and on initial load it is not pre-selected with a valid option. Like,

```
this.form = this.formbuilder.group({
 sport: ''
});
```

You can look for its value change in the template to show the corresponding secondary dropdown for varieties.

Assuming you have a 'property' to hold the value of varieties at any given instant based on the selected value, in your component listen for the first select control's value change,

```
varieties: any[] = null; // declare varieties property in component   

this.form.get('sport').valueChanges
  .subscribe((newVal) => {
    if (!newval) {
      this.varieties = null;
    } else {
      this.varieties = this.sports.filter((elem) => elem.id === newVal)[0].varieties;
      // assuming each newVal is actually the property value of 'id' based on '[value]="sport.id"' <-- this assignment in the template
    }
  });
```

Now simply add this new select dropdown as well to your template,

```
<select formControlName="sport">
    <option value="">- Select -</option>
    <option *ngFor="let sport of sports | async" [value]="sport.id">{{sport.name}}</option>
</select>
<select *ngIf="varities">
    <option value="">- Select -</option>
    <option *ngFor="let variety of varities" [value]="variety.name">{{variety.name}}</option>
</select>
```

You might have to modify the code based on the actual `value` to be assigned for this new select dropdown and might even add a new formControl for the varieties selection. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I had to make some changes but it definitely helped point me in the right direction, particularly using the valueChanges function on the form value.

Comment: @Daniel Hutton What kind of changes did you make? I've tried to do the same thing (even the json has the same structure), but the `elem.id` is causing error... Could you please share your code snippet?